# Mysql select from one table

Tags: mysql

My Table structure is

```
id;product_id;sell_type;sell_state

sell_type: BUY, SELL

sell_state: OPEN, FILLED, CANCELED
```

How to select only `product_id` with each 2 operation, `BUY & SELL` in `sell_type` and `FILLED` in `sell_state`

```
CREATE TABLE `orderlist` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sell_type` enum('BUY','SELL') DEFAULT NULL,
  `sell_state` enum('OPEN','FILLED','CANCELED') DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `orderlist` (`id`, `product_id`, `sell_type`, `sell_state`) VALUES
(7, 1, 'BUY', 'FILLED'),
(8, 1, 'SELL', 'FILLED'),
(9, 2, 'BUY', 'FILLED'),
(10, 3, 'SELL', 'FILLED');
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: need group by 2 field: sell_type and product_id

Comment: What have you tried so far??????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a group by and count(distinct sell_state) = 2

```
select product_id 
from orderlist  
where sell_state ='FILLED'
and sell_type in ('BUY', 'SELL')
group by product_id 
having count(distinct sell_type) = 2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c41301/2

Comment: what mean "don't work" ... you have error ? show error message ... wrong result show your expected  result and you actula result    and a proper (clear) data sample for the expectedc result

Comment: update your question and  show a clear and proper data sample and the related  expected  result  ..

Comment: CREATE TABLE `orderlist` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sell_type` enum('BUY','SELL') DEFAULT NULL,
  `sell_state` enum('OPEN','FILLED','CANCELED') DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `orderlist` (`id`, `product_id`, `sell_type`, `sell_state`) VALUES
(7, 1, 'BUY', 'FILLED'),
(8, 1, 'SELL', 'FILLED'),
(9, 2, 'BUY', 'FILLED'),
(10, 3, 'SELL', 'FILLED');

Comment: If you don't declare the expected  result and change  .. the term of the sample  ..  your are not  playing fair  .. anyway the sqlfddle return  1 and 2 for product id  ..  both with FILLED and BUY and SELL

Comment: thanks for helping. sorry for my mistake, english is not my native language

Comment: But me need select product_id, which have sell and buy BOTH.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c41301/2  return 1  .. SELL and BUY both  .. not 2 or 3 (only SELL ,  only BUY)

Answer (score 1):

try this select query

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM temp t1
INNER JOIN temp t2
ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id AND FIND_IN_SET('FILLED',t1.sell_state) > 0
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('BUY',t1.sell_type) > 0 AND
CONCAT(",", t2.sell_type, ",") REGEXP ",(BUY|SELL),"
GROUP BY t1.product_id
```

demo : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7fcd9/64

Comment: No, need select who have each sell_type

Comment: then which type of data you need .??

Comment: select product_id only have 2 sell_type: buy & sell. if product_id have only sell or by - not need

Comment: CREATE TABLE orderlist ( id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, product_id int(11) NOT NULL, sell_type enum('BUY','SELL') DEFAULT NULL, sell_state enum('OPEN','FILLED','CANCELED') DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;  INSERT INTO orderlist (id, product_id, sell_type, sell_state) VALUES (7, 1, 'BUY', 'FILLED'), (8, 1, 'SELL', 'FILLED'), (9, 2, 'BUY', 'FILLED'), (10, 3, 'SELL', 'FILLED');

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT product_id
FROM orderlist
WHERE sell_state = 'FILLED' AND sell_type IN ('BUY','SELL')
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(product_id) > 2
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/464959/2

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b895ba/1 if we have 2 sales or buyes - not work

Comment: check it now @cryptodoxer here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/464959/2 and updated the answer too